# Short Circuit that only makes certain electronics go out?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, circuit

Yesterday at around 11 PM we had a short circuit that lasted just a split second. I was in my office with my back turned when I saw the lights flicker. Then, I went to the kitchen and the same thing happened. Not a big deal. But somehow, the TV and fan in our bedroom also went out, despite the TV not being connected to the other one and in a different place in the house. Also, the clocks in the bedroom weren't affected by this shortcircuit. Does anyone know how this is possible?

P.S. I know it helps to have pictures, I can't get them right now, I'm a work until 7, but I'll try to get some then.

Comment: Does the equipment that shut off (tvs, fan) turn back on? This sounds like it could be a momentary voltage drop/surge on the grid rather than problems with your wiring or equipment. Sometimes surges can damage sensitive equipment but other items (like clocks) could be unaffected.

Comment: Yes they cut back on almost instantly. I did forget to mention its a digital clock though, that resets whenever unplugged.

Comment: I don't think [that word](https://www.thespruce.com/what-causes-short-circuits-4118973) means what you think it means.

Comment: Yep i misspelled and hit enter too early

Comment: Was that directed at me? My point is that a short circuit trips breakers and blows fuses. This isn't that.

Comment: Oh I apologize, I accidently said "almsot" and didn't see the link. I assumed you meant that, my mistake.

Comment: @bigchief I forgot to mention this, two of our clocks aren't super sensitive so I could see this with them. But the other one in my room is very sensitive. If I unplug it it goes out instantly and usually in power outages it'll go out right when the power does. And also for your question about them cutting back on, I also forgot to add that the TV resets, i assume thats what you meant, it just didnt go back to cable instantly or anything

Comment: @bigchief is it strange for the grid to drop momentarily twice within 10 to 15 seconds though?

Comment: I think the grid losing power twice momentarily in a short time is certainly possible and is my best guess at what happened.

Answer (score 5):

There was probably a fault on the power grid and one of their circuit breakers operated and you experienced a momentary interruption of power, not a short circuit. These can happen a few times at a time while their breaker clears or isolates their problem. This is a very common occurrence in the utility business and many appliances had builtin devices that will tolerate a brief interruption but many still don't which is why you have to reset some clocks, TV's and microwaves and others don't need to be reset.
If you have critical equipment that is affected, you can get an uninterruptible power source from any computer store.

Comment: Having worked for a power company for a while, these are called "reclosers". When a wet limb or a big squirrel or bird shorts out power lines, the breaker trips, and the recloser closes it again. The assumption is that it was a momentary incident and will most likely clear itself. The REMCs I worked with all had their reclosers try 3 times*, after that, the circuit would stay open and the power would be out until linemen came and fixed the problem. *I don't know if this was adjustable or simply the standard.

Comment: Yes but why would the lights go out and still keep the digital clock on? It's also a very sensitive clock that resets when unplugged or when the power goes out, yet it stayed on the whole time.

Comment: @HuCooper if the power drop was brief enough, then yes, the clock may have stayed on. Pulling the plug & plugging it back in is a _sloooow_ event in electrical terms.

Comment: Yeah but usually it resets the instant it stops receiving power. I know this probably was a much faster event that unplugging it, but it just seems pretty weird

Comment: Plus, how would the clock stay on if the fan went out?

Comment: @HuCooper  The clocks take very little power to run so designing a circuit with a few capacitors to maintain voltage during a breaker trip so people don't over sleep is pretty simple. Whereas fans wouldn't need this.

Comment: @FreeMan   The reclosers on the breakers are adjustable. The reclosers on all underground feeders are usually set for a one shot because there's little chance of a fault clearing itself and closing in on a faulted cable additional times would further weaken the cable.   On overhead systems, the reclosers are set to a three shot and the time between them can vary.  You can also just turn them off so the don't reclose at all. You'd do this if linemen were working on the line, if they cause a fault, you wouldn't want to reclose in it three times.

Comment: I do agree, but like I said, every other time the powers gone out the clock has too

Comment: @HuCooper  That would depend on the length of time the power's out. My clocks will take a two or three second blip but any more than that and I'm resetting them.  My microwave goes out immediately and stays off.

Comment: The power was out for no more than 0.5 seconds I'd say. I'm not exactly sure how my clock works, I just know that if I unplug it it goes out instantly. Although I think you may be right, the unplugging of it may be longer than the span of time the light was out for, so it was able to survive just barely. I was also wondering if it's possible the power didn't even go out there? It's in the same outlet as the TV cords, but I've heard of certain outlets being affected while the other may not be, I'm wondering if that's possible too.

Comment: @HuCooper  Those breakers will reclose in .5 seconds and even faster depending on the settings. We had some set in Florida that reclosed in .3 seconds. I can't imagine different outlets being affected differently, only what's plugged into them.  It's the digital components that are usually  affected my these momentary interruptions.

Comment: Ok thanks, it might've been even faster now that i think back. It was basically a quick flicker and it cut back, maybe even 0.2 or 0.3 seconds. I just don't get why, if this is the explanation, why it resets so fast when I unplug the clock. That has to be around 0.2 or 0.3 seconds too